# Add method to existing class you don't own in javascript

Tags: javascript, monkey-patch

Is it still called monkey patching if you are only adding new methods instead of changing existing method behavior? What is this called?

Example:

```
String.prototype.contains = function(needle) { return false; }
```

That may not be the best example, but it shows how you can achieve this.

**What are some pitfalls of this technique and what are some attempts to get around them?**

Comment: It's called "adding a method to an existing class in Javascript."  [This post](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html) uses the phrase "dynamically creating properties and methods of existing objects through simple assignment."

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have classes, so it's called "impossible".

Comment: Object prototyping? `Array.prototype.newMethod = function() {}`. It's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: @gardenhead - [ES2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) introduces a concept called `class` in javascript - it's syntactic sugar, but, technically, javascript now has something that is called classes

Answer (score 2):

It's still called monkey patching. Any modification of the class itself that happens far from it's official declaration is monkey patching.

Monkey patching IMO has two main pitfalls:

1. Method definition become harder to search. When one wants to look at a method's definition they usually go to the class' definition. When the method is monkey patched, the method's code and comments won't be there - or even worse, if the method is replace then the original method will be there, with no indication that it was replaced with something else.
2. You now depend on hidden module loading. Yes, you were always depending on module loading, but now the dependency becomes more implicit.

   Usually you know that if you are creating a new `Foo` you need to load `foo.js` first(or whatever module `Foo` is defined in). Or, if you received a `Foo` from somewhere else, you know that `foo.js` was loaded there. Even if you somehow created a `Foo` without loading `foo.js` because someone else loaded it for you, and that someone else removed the command that loads `foo.js`, when your code breaks it's usually vert easy to solve - you get an error that `Foo` is an unknown identifier, so you look where it's defined and load it.

   Monkey patching is not so easy. `unrelated.js` may add `Foo.bar`, and you may be using it without loading `unrelated.js` yourself. Then someone removes it's dependency on `unrelated.js`, or maybe you created a new script and just loaded `foo.js`, and suddenly your `Foo` objects no longer have `bar`. You are going to bang your head against the wall several times before you'll realize that you need to load `unrelated.js`.

My solution? If you need to use monkey patching, try to limit it to framework and infrastructure code, and not use it in library or application code. This greatly reduces the risks, because:

- Framework and infrastructures are already allowed to redefine the rules of the language. Ruby on Rails is a notable example: you are already deeply aware that you are no longer programming Ruby - you are programming RoR - so the monkey patched classes are just another modification you need to be aware of.
- Frameworks and infrastructures usually handle their own module loading to guarantee they work properly, so they can guarantee that all the monkey patching code is loaded.
- Frameworks and infrastructures have their own conventions, and if you are aware of those you can easily find the definitions of monkey patched methods.

P.S.: Some compiled static languages have some facilities that resemble monkey patching - like extension methods in C# or Rust's `struct`/`impl` separation. These facilities do not have those pitfalls, because the methods you define do not become part of the class. They are only using the class' namespace, and are still belong to the module/scope they are defined in.

Comment: Aren't name important to being able to do further research? If I don't know what it is called, how do I google it or recognize when other people are talking about it?

Comment: @still_dreaming_1: Most questions like this assume that there's a name for everything, and that everything has a name.  It doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But wouldn't it be good to know if a name for it does exist? If no name exists for it yet, that is good to know too. Basically you are saying we should limit our vocabulary to only a few words and then have to use many of them to express any idea and then ignore anything we hear that uses an expanded vocabulary.

Comment: @still_dreaming_1: What I am actually saying is that the learning process encompasses far more than vocabulary lessons.